# Material Ui card change according to input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have used material ui card and when i display it. It shows like below image. I want to show my card like that when cards do not fit the page it goes below and all card size must be same. How can i do that?

Here is my code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({ // Styling for my cards
  root: {
    width: 255,// i changed that line and below line but nothing happened
  },
  media: {
    height: 190,
  },
});

export default function AlbumsCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
 ..... //Some http requests
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          style={{
            width: 500,
            "margin-left": "auto",
            "margin-right": "auto",
            "margin-top": "10px",
          }}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Album"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={input}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}> //cardss
        {k.map((album) => (
          <Link
            to={`/albums/${album.album_id}`}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#15cdfc" }}
          >
            <Card style={{ margin: "10px" }} className={classes.root}>
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  className={classes.media}
                  image={album.album_pfp}
                  title={album.album_name}
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {album.album_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                  >
                    {album.album_song_count}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also the image from my app:

[image]

You can see that above. All cards placed in a line and some cards height's are different. Also there is a scroll bar.

I want to display whole card i a same size and when it overflows the page. It goes below.

---

Updated version:
[image: Image2]

Now each card has a different size how can i solve that? I think it is from image size.

Comment: try to use display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap on the container, then flex: 1 and display: flex on each item container, and remove overflow property

Comment: I updated the image can you check that? @Alopwer

Comment: there is a trick, you can use (min-height f.e. 200px and then height: 0px) on each card, or if it doesn't help just use min-height: value px on each card

Comment: or try to remove display: flex from each card and just leave there flex: 1

Comment: Nothng changed. Still same @Alopwer